# PowerApps - Choices(Table.Column) doesn't work with SQL data source?

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to create a gallery in Power Apps from a SQL table.
I want to use **Choices** to create a delegable list of distinct values from a particular column - NB: It must be delegable because the table contains thousands of rows so **Distinct** or **Group By** won't work.

With Sharepoint, you can do something like **Choices(DataSource.Column)** and it's fine, but this doesn't seem to work with SQL... How can I use **Choices** with a SQL data source?

Thanks.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Not really a SQL problem, just need to get a delegable list of distinct values in PowerApps

Comment: Then you can remove the <sql> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `Choices()` function for your requirements to get distinct column values from SQL.

Also `Choices()` function is not delegable currently:

> At this time, you can't [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) Choices. If this limitation poses a problem in your app, add the foreign table as a data source, and use it directly.

**Source**: [Choices function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-choices?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

---

Here is what we are doing in our applications to get the distinct column values from SQL:

1. Create a SQL view based on table, example:

```
CREATE VIEW vDistinct_Countries
AS SELECT DISTINCT country_name
FROM Countries
```

2. Add the newly created view (`vDistinct_Countries`) as data source in your app.
3. Use the newly created view directly on the `items` property of gallery to have the delegable query:

```
vDistinct_Countries
```